# How to transfer SQL deletes to destination staging tables?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build ADF Pipeline that will be used to move delete operation from SQL on-premise to Azure SQL Database, am using the staging tables in destination and from there am comparing the records from staging destination tables to destination main tables.

Problem is how can I insert deleted row records to staging table and then compare it with destination main tables and replicate the same in azure how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Flows in ADF https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaxIlI7oXfI

You can use transformations like Exists to compare for the existence of records across data stores and Alter Row to set update/insert/upsert/delete policies.

Comment: We cannot use Data flows, since our source is on-premise.SQL